# How to disable a function for X seconds when another button clicked in As3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop

I have simple question that it became complected for me which is:

I have a function which is called and run after around 11 seconds:

```
var myTimeoutClickObject = setTimeout(clickObject,11000); 
function clickObject():void{
  //My code
}
```

I also have a Reset Button that I made a Click Function for it:

```
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);
function reset(e:MouseEvent):void{
  //My code
}
```

Now, I want to make the `clickObject()` function disabled for around 11 seconds again every time that I click on the `reset_btn` Button.

I really appreciate, if you can help me in this matter!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know what a Boolean is? Set a Boolean variable to indicate that the reset button was click and simultaneously add a timer that will go for 11 seconds. When that timer is up, remove the timer and reset the Boolean value. Then make your function that you are trying to disable only work if that Boolean is in the correct state

Answer (score 2):

You can make it using flag:

```
var isClickDisabled:Boolean = false;

var myTimeoutClickObject = setTimeout(clickObject, 11000);

function clickObject():void{
    //My code
    if(isClickDisabled)
       return;
}

reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(e:MouseEvent):void{
  //My code
  isClickDisabled = true;

  // call code to re-enable it later for 11sec
}
```

Or use clearTimeout like this:

```
clearTimeout(myTimeoutClickObject);

setTimeout(startAgain_clickObject, 11000);

function startAgain_clickObject(e:MouseEvent):void {
      myTimeoutClickObject = setTimeout(clickObject, 11000);
}
```